# Handlebars displaying JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I am trying to iterate over each item in a JSON array using handlebars. However I can't get any of the JSON data below to display. Here is my code:

HTML

```
{{#each entries}}
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{day}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{content}}
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

...

```
<script>

var entries = {

  entries: [
    {
      day: "Day 1",
      content: "THIS is TEST CONTENT"
    },
    {
      day: "Day 2",
      content: "THIS is TEST CONTENT2"
    }
  ]
};

</script>
```

I tried the same - http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/ and it worked perfectly, what seems to be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please also show the part where you are compiling and rendering the template

Comment: Try `#each entries.entries`

Comment: have you tried with `this`. E.g. `{{this.day}}`, `{{this.content}}`?

Comment: Thanks but entries.entries does not work, nor does this.day. As for compiling, I tried a few different suggestions online but none worked so I was hoping someone could show the correct way of compiling and rendering?

Comment: `someone could show the correct way of compiling and rendering?` 
  https://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this Flow of this implementation :

HTML:

```
<h1>Handlebars JS Example</h1>
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> <table>
    <thead> 
        <th>Name</th> 
        <th>Job Title</th> 
        <th>Twitter</th> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        {{#users}} 
        <tr> 
            <td>{{person.firstName}}</td> 
            <td>{{jobTitle}}</td> 
            <td><a href="https://twitter.com/{{twitter}}">@{{twitter}}</a></td> 
        </tr> 
        {{/users}} 
    </tbody> 
</table> 
</script>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE :

```
var source = $("#some-template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var data = { 
    users: [ { 
        person: {
            firstName: "Garry", 
            lastName: "Finch"
        },
        jobTitle: "Front End Technical Lead",
        twitter: "gazraa" 
    }, {
        person: {
            firstName: "Garry", 
            lastName: "Finch"
        }, 
        jobTitle: "Photographer",
        twitter: "photobasics"
    }, {
        person: {
            firstName: "Garry", 
            lastName: "Finch"
        }, 
        jobTitle: "LEGO Geek",
        twitter: "minifigures"
    } ]
}; 

$('body').append(template(data));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately the code doesn't work. It doesn't throw an error but nothing is rendered other than the header.

Comment: Are you using latest Handlebars.js and include after Jquery.js file ?

Comment: I am yeah, latest of both. No handlebars/jquery errors are being shown.